# Select Folder Picker VBA stops and does not continue the code

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to select a folder and then assign that path to my file Variant. However, the code stops after the folder is selected and does not go to the next step. What can be wrong? The next step would be 'If selected_folder <> "" Then' but it just stops and debugger goes back to Sub.

```
Sub sheetCompare2()

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    Dim i As Integer
    Dim WS_Count As Integer
    Dim mDirs As String
    Dim path As String
    Dim OutFile As Variant, SrcFile As Variant
    Dim file As Variant
    Dim wb As Workbook
    Dim datevar As Variant
    Dim datevar2 As Variant
    
    Dim selected_folder As String
  
    Set wb = ThisWorkbook
    WS_Count = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets.Count
    OutFile = ActiveWorkbook.Name

    With Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)
    .Title = "Select a Folder"
    If Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker).Show = -1 Then
        selected_folder = .SelectedItems(1)
        
    End If
End With

  If selected_folder <> "" Then
    file = Dir(selected_folder)
    End If
    While (file <> "")
        path = selected_folder + file
        Workbooks.Open (path)
        SrcFile = ActiveWorkbook.Name
        datevar = Right(file, 9)
        datevar2 = Left(datevar, 4)

....'and so on

End Sub
```

Comment: `file = Dir(selected_folder)` does not return anything if not an extension is supplied. Of course, using the whiled character. Even `"*.*"`. Please, check the piece of code I suggested in my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please, try changing this part of the code:

```
If selected_folder <> "" Then
    file = Dir(selected_folder)
    End If
    While (file <> "")
        path = mDirs + file
        Workbooks.Open (path)
        SrcFile = ActiveWorkbook.Name
        datevar = Right(file, 9)
        datevar2 = Left(datevar, 4)

'....'and so on
```

with:

```
  If selected_folder <> "" Then
     File = Dir(selected_folder & "\" & "*.xls*")
  End If
    Do While File <> ""
        path = selected_folder & "\" & File
        Workbooks.Open (path)
        SrcFile = ActiveWorkbook.Name
        datevar = Right(File, 9)
        datevar2 = left(datevar, 4)
        
        File = Dir
       '...
   Loop
```

In order to make `Dir` return a file name, you must set an extension. At least `*.*` for iterate between all files. But, wanting to open the files in Excel, it is good to use `"*.xls*"`, as the above code does.

Then, the path of the file to be open should be built as above.

Your code does not show how you redefine `File` in order to make the loop working. You maybe have `File = Dir` before the loop end. If not, I added...